# How to get the values of multiple radio button groups with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a catering order form and I would like the user to see what they ordered. The form consists of eleven different packages, so it's not a good idea hard code it for each package. Each package has an entree, a salad, and the delivery time, and radio buttons are used. This is my HTML code. (I've deleted some lines to reduce the amount of code here) 
Thanks!

```
    <form id="orderForm">
<!--     first package-->
        <div>
            <h3> First Package</h3>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="Entree Item" value="Mustang Hot Dog"> Mustang Hot Dog <br>
                <input type="radio" name="Entree Item" value="Nacho Station"> Nacho Station <br>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="Salad Name" value="Ceasar"> Ceasar <br>
                <input type="radio" name="Salad Name" value="Pasta">  Pasta <br>
                <input type="radio" name="Salad Name" value="Seasonal Fruit Salad"> Seasonal Fruit Salad <br>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time" value="Pre Game"> Pre Game <br>
                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time" value="Kick Off"> Kick Off <br>
                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time" value="Half Time"> Half Time <br>
            </div>
        </div>

<!--second package-->
        <div>
            <h3>Second Package </h3>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="Entree Item" value="Tri-Tip Sandwiches"> Tri-Tip Sandwiches <br>
                <input type="radio" name="Entree Item" value="Nacho Station"> Chili Bar <br>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="Salad Name" value="Ceasar"> Ceasar <br>
                <input type="radio" name="Salad Name" value="Pasta">  Pasta <br>
                <input type="radio" name="Salad Name" value="Seasonal Fruit Salad"> Seasonal Fruit Salad <br>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time" value="Pre Game"> Pre Game <br>
                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time" value="Kick Off"> Kick Off <br>
                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time" value="Half Time"> Half Time <br>
            </div>
        </div>
<!--        Third package-->
<!-- ... -->
<!--   Eleventh Package-->
    </form>
```

This is my jQuery code. I was only able to output the value of one group of entree items. I just started using jQuery/JS so I'm not sure how I would output the values of each radio group of each food package.

```
$('input[name=Entree Item]:checked', '#orderForm').val()
$('#orderForm input').on('change', function() {
    $('#val').text($('input[name=Entree Item]:checked', '#orderForm').val());
});
```

So this is what I would like the user to see:
Name of package:xxxxxxx
Entree selected:xxxxxxx
Salad selected:xxxxxxx
Delivery time:xxxxxxx
 
And if the user bough more than one package I would also like to output the value of those packages too. 
Thank you!!

Comment: I don't see any Javascript here...? Have you tried *anything*?

Comment: Please see my updated code. I added what I did with JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As long as the structure remains the same**, to summarize the selected items/orders and their values, iterate over each package in a separated `summarizePackages` function, narrow down each selected `entree`, `salad`, and `delivery`, then according to their value, display their summary in the `#val` element under the form.

**Also make sure** to have different `name` attributes for the radio button groups in different packages to avoid confusion and cross-package-group selection (e.g.: for the `1st` package, suffix your `name` attributes with `1`, like: `Entree Item 1`, `Salad Name 1`, and `Delivery Time 1` and so on for the following packages).

```js
function summarizePackages() {  
  var packages = $('#orderForm > div');
  var summary = '';
  
  packages.each(function(index, pkg) {
    pkg = $(pkg);
    
    var name = $.trim(pkg.find('h3').text());
    var entree = pkg.find('[name^="Entree Item"]:checked');
    var salad = pkg.find('[name^="Salad Name"]:checked');    
    var delivery = pkg.find('[name^="Delivery Time"]:checked');
    var hasOrder = pkg.find('input:checked').length > 0;
    
    if (hasOrder) {
      summary += 'Name of package: <b>' + name + '</b>';
      summary += '<br>';
    
      if (entree.length) {
        summary += 'Entree selected: <b>' + entree.val() + '</b>';
      } else {
        summary += 'No Entree selected';
      }    
      summary += '<br>';

      if (salad.length) {
        summary += 'Salad selected: <b>' + salad.val() + '</b>';
      } else {
        summary += 'No Salad selected';
      }    
      summary += '<br>';

      if (delivery.length) {
        summary += 'Delivery selected: <b>' + delivery.val() + '</b>';   
      } else {
        summary += 'No Delivery selected';
      }    
      summary += '<br>';

      summary += '--------------------';
      summary += '<br>';
    }
  });
  
  return summary;
}

$('#orderForm input').on('change', function() {
    var summary = summarizePackages();    
    $('#val').html(summary);
});
```

```css
#val {
  margin: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="orderForm">
  <!--     first package-->
  <div>
    <h3> First Package</h3>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="Entree Item 1" value="Mustang Hot Dog"> Mustang Hot Dog <br>
      <input type="radio" name="Entree Item 1" value="Nacho Station"> Nacho Station <br>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="Salad Name 1" value="Ceasar"> Ceasar <br>
      <input type="radio" name="Salad Name 1" value="Pasta"> Pasta <br>
      <input type="radio" name="Salad Name 1" value="Seasonal Fruit Salad"> Seasonal Fruit Salad <br>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time 1" value="Pre Game"> Pre Game <br>
      <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time 1" value="Kick Off"> Kick Off <br>
      <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time 1" value="Half Time"> Half Time <br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--second package-->
  <div>
    <h3>Second Package </h3>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="Entree Item 2" value="Tri-Tip Sandwiches"> Tri-Tip Sandwiches <br>
      <input type="radio" name="Entree Item 2" value="Nacho Station"> Chili Bar <br>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="Salad Name 2" value="Ceasar"> Ceasar <br>
      <input type="radio" name="Salad Name 2" value="Pasta"> Pasta <br>
      <input type="radio" name="Salad Name 2" value="Seasonal Fruit Salad"> Seasonal Fruit Salad <br>      
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time 2" value="Pre Game"> Pre Game <br>
      <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time 2" value="Kick Off"> Kick Off <br>
      <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time 2" value="Half Time"> Half Time <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--        Third package-->
  <!-- ... -->
  <!--   Eleventh Package-->
</form>
<div id="val"></div>
```

Modify the summarizer function (`summarizePackages`) according to your actual needs.

Comment: Thanks Rick! What do I do so the user is not notified for not selecting other packages?

Comment: No problem! If you mean, that the message `No order selected from this package` shouldn't be displayed, than I'll update my code, if you mean, that the radio-button-groups modify each other cross-package, than use suffixes for the `name` attributes e.g. `Entree Item 1`, `Salad Name 1`, and `Delivery Time 1` and so on for the following packages. Get back to me on what you've meant.

Comment: Yes I don't want the user to see "No order selected from this package" because there are 11 packages. Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer, please, check it out whether it's working for you, If not, tell me, if it's the working solution to your problem, mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Edit kopok1o295]

Maybe try to add a submit button and loop through selected radio

```
  $("#submit").click(function () {
    $(".package").each(function(){

      $(this).find("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function(){

        console.log($(this).attr("name"), $(this).val())

      })

    })
  })
```

Also, your packages are sharing the same radio names, so it may be a good idea to change that to let users select things in different packages

Answer (score 1):

As far as you have tried, this is how you would do it. Its also important to change the `name` attribute of the `input` elements of your every package.

*Check the working snippet.* Select an item from any package and scroll down.

This would become tedious if you have dozens of packages and I would strongly suggest you would go how **Jayffe** has suggested in his answer.

```js
$('#orderForm input').on('change', function() {
   if($('input[name="Entree Item"]').is(':checked')) {
   $('#first-package').show();
      $('#entree').text($('input[name="Entree Item"]:checked', '#orderForm').val());
      $('#salad').text($('input[name="Salad Name"]:checked', '#orderForm').val());
      $('#time').text($('input[name="Delivery Time"]:checked', '#orderForm').val());
    }
    
    if($('input[name="Entree Item-second"]').is(':checked')) {
      $('#second-package').show();
      $('#entree-sec').text($('input[name="Entree Item-second"]:checked', '#orderForm').val());
      $('#salad-sec').text($('input[name="Salad Name-second"]:checked', '#orderForm').val());
      $('#time-sec').text($('input[name="Delivery Time-second"]:checked', '#orderForm').val());
    }
});
```

```css
#second-package, #first-package {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="orderForm">
<!--     first package-->
        <div>
            <h3> First Package</h3>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="Entree Item" value="Mustang Hot Dog"> Mustang Hot Dog <br>
                <input type="radio" name="Entree Item" value="Nacho Station"> Nacho Station <br>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="Salad Name" value="Ceasar"> Ceasar <br>
                <input type="radio" name="Salad Name" value="Pasta">  Pasta <br>
                <input type="radio" name="Salad Name" value="Seasonal Fruit Salad"> Seasonal Fruit Salad <br>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time" value="Pre Game"> Pre Game <br>
                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time" value="Kick Off"> Kick Off <br>
                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time" value="Half Time"> Half Time <br>
            </div>
        </div>

<!--second package-->
        <div>
            <h3>Second Package </h3>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="Entree Item-second" value="Tri-Tip Sandwiches"> Tri-Tip Sandwiches <br>
                <input type="radio" name="Entree Item-second" value="Nacho Station"> Chili Bar <br>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="Salad Name-second" value="Ceasar"> Ceasar <br>
                <input type="radio" name="Salad Name-second" value="Pasta">  Pasta <br>
                <input type="radio" name="Salad Name-second" value="Seasonal Fruit Salad"> Seasonal Fruit Salad <br>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time-second" value="Pre Game"> Pre Game <br>
                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time-second" value="Kick Off"> Kick Off <br>
                <input type="radio" name="Delivery Time-second" value="Half Time"> Half Time <br>
            </div>
        </div>
<!--        Third package-->
<!-- ... -->
<!--   Eleventh Package-->
    </form>
    
    <div id="first-package">
      <div>
        <label>Name of Package:</label>
        <span>First</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Entree Selected:</label>
        <span id="entree"></span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Salad Selected:</label>
        <span id="salad"></span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Delivery Time:</label>
        <span id="time"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="second-package">
      <div>
        <label>Name of Package:</label>
        <span>Second</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Entree Selected:</label>
        <span id="entree-sec"></span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Salad Selected:</label>
        <span id="salad-sec"></span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Delivery Time:</label>
        <span id="time-sec"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
```